# Addng css files in React project with Webpack 4

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-4

I am building a simple React app from scratch using Webpack.
I was finally able to run the dev server and when I tried to apply some styles via CSS, the files wouldn't load and I assume my Webpack 4 configuration is not right.

Here is the code:

**webpack.config.js**

```
// const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

const path = require('path');


module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: ['./src/index.js'],
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".js", ".jsx"]
    },
    output: {
      filename: 'main.js',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
      publicPath: '/dist',
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        compress: true,
        port: 8080
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js|.jsx$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                options: {
                    presets: ["react"]
                }

            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
                loader: 'url-loader'
            }
        ]
    },

};
```

My project structure is like this, I will include only **src** because it lives in the root:

```
 **src**
      |_assets
      |_componentns
      |_styles
        |_App.css
        |_index.css
      App.jsx
      index.js
      index.html
```

I would like to be able to add multiple css files for each component I have and apply them, and to be able to style the index the **index.html**.
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Are the css files injected into `style` tags in `html`? Try inspecting that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is import the CSS files when needed as you would a JavaScript module. So if you want to have a style sheet for your whole application, you can import a global stylesheet in your `index.js`.

```
import './styles/index.css';
```

and you can do the same for each component with specific styles

```
import './styles/App.css'
```

in which case you might want to [setup CSS modules](https://javascriptplayground.com/css-modules-webpack-react/) to avoid overlapping class names.

Comment: I have already done that, still not working  and there are no erros :/

Answer (score 2):

Your `webpack` configuration looks fine.
make sure you `import` the required `css` files in your `components`.

```
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I do that but still nothing shows. I will update the code.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, rookie mistake here, the way I ahve set up webpack is I have to build it first and then run the dev server, no the other way around.
All answers above are valid and helpful, I just forgot to run build after changes.